# How to send a newline in a message to websocket

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Edit: According to my research the problem is the text is put inside of a textnode which prevents it from being processed as html. Because of this all of the answers up to now didn't work.

I am sending some messages with websockets from a python script. Since I don't have any experience with websockets and Javascript, I have simply taken some example code and customized the message sent to my needs.

Sending the message is fine but I need to include newline commands inside of the message. I have tried including \n and "< br>" into the message but they are just printed to the html page.

the .html looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" >
            <title>Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>
                var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5678/"),
                    messages = document.createElement('ul');
                ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                    var messages = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
                        message = document.createElement('li'),
                        content = document.createTextNode(event.data);
                    message.appendChild(content);
                    messages.appendChild(message);
                };
                document.body.appendChild(messages);
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace \n with `<br>`, remember you work with html

```
message = message.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a CSS white-space Property

`document.body.style = "white-space: pre;"`

From the documentation:
`pre => Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the <pre> tag in HTML`

Comment: did not work unfortunately. reason is the text is inside of a textnode as stated in my edit

Answer (score -2):

Did you put the '\n' in quotes? It doesn't work without the quotes